# Quarkus discovering of JAXRS-Endpoints

Tags: quarkus

I'am currently trying to understand the discovering of JAXRS-Endpoints in Quarkus. My assumption is that they are automatically discovered and there is no need to register them. In addition I tried to import Endpoints from an other module/jar File. It is working to out of the box.

But than I tried to understand the order of discovering endpoints.

I tried to overwrite a jar file provided endpoint in my application, but it is not working. Therfore in my opinion there is a potential security problem, if any third party module can overwrite my endpoints. Has anyone the same problems and can provide me informations how to think about this problem? (My only solution is to write an own extension which removes all endpoints an add only the ones I want to have, but I think this is against the idea)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you are actually wondering what happens when there are multiple JAX-RS paths that match?

Comment: yes, that would be the simplified question

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate endpoint detection was added to RESTEasy Reactive in https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/15037.

This means that from version `2.7.0.CR1` and on, Quarkus will fail the build if duplicate JAX-RS endpoints are defined (assuming you are using `quarkus-resteasy-reactive`).

Comment: I'm using `quarkus-resteasy`, is there anything like this planned?

Comment: No, there is not. RESTEasy Reactive is our focus going forward